# How to set a dynamic env var in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I want to add a dynamic env var in my node.js app, in other words i wanted the env value to be determined through a function. so i can't add it manually in my .env file.
I'am using webpack as a module bundler and i want to access that env var in my webpack.config file.

Comment: You should only read your environment variables from one place in your application. Create a config JS file which collects all env variables and exports a config Object which you can pass to your application. This way, you can always "hijack" your env variables, for testing, for example. And the advantage is that you can run a function and add the result in there for your app to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running the node server on a linux machine. You need to export all your environment variables manually or via a script like so: `export PORT=3000;`, then accesses them directly via the node `process object` like so:
`const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;`.

Or you could install a dependency like config (https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) and have it manage pulling your environment variables into the code for use.

Comment: Yes i added it in my config/defaults.js file, i can access it now from src folder but not from webpack.config.js which was my goal at the start.
although i've access to env vars in my .env (locally) through process.env.env_name in webpack.config.js, i can't access env vars declared in default file.
any idea?

Comment: Check this (https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) out. According to the link webpack does not play 100% by the OS's rules when it comes to env vars. So you're gonna have to work up some unorthodox solution.